Android Jetpack Compose Infinite Scroll with Paginated API calls
I request API call from developer.themoviedb.org with page parameter, I want to get another page when scroll reach the bottom.
Is this best case? Whats your suggestions for optimize code?
Here is my viewModel:
@HiltViewModel
class PopularMoviesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val contentRepository: ContentRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf<ScreenState<List<Movie>>>(ScreenState.Loading)
    val state: State<ScreenState<List<Movie>>> get() = _state

    private val movieList: MutableList<Movie> = mutableListOf()

    init {
        getPopularMovies(1)
    }

    fun getPopularMovies(page: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        println("getPopularMovies Runned")
        contentRepository.getPopularMovies(page).collect { response ->
            when (response) {
                is NetworkResponseState.Error -> _state.value =
                    ScreenState.Error(response.exception.message.toString())

                is NetworkResponseState.Loading -> {
                    _state.value = ScreenState.Loading
                }

                is NetworkResponseState.Success -> {
                    println("getPopularMovies Success")
                    movieList.addAll(response.result)
                    _state.value = ScreenState.Success(movieList)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

This model get first page on init, after get another page when scroll reached bottom
Here is my screen;

@Composable
fun PopularMoviesScreen(
    viewModel: PopularMoviesViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    onBack: () -> Unit
) {
    var list by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<Movie>()) }
    var pageCounter by remember { mutableIntStateOf(1) }
    val listState = rememberLazyGridState()
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        listState.scrollToItem(20 * (pageCounter - 1))
    }
    when (val popularMoviesState = viewModel.state.value) {
        is ScreenState.Success -> {
            list = popularMoviesState.uiData
            PopularMoviesSuccessContent(
                movieList = popularMoviesState.uiData,
                onBack = onBack,
                onSearch = {
                    pageCounter++
                    viewModel.getPopularMovies(pageCounter)
                },
                state = listState
            )
        }

        is ScreenState.Loading -> {
            PopularMoviesLoadingContent(onBack = onBack, list, state = listState)
        }

        is ScreenState.Error -> {
            ErrorScreen(
                message = popularMoviesState.message,
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PopularMoviesSuccessContent(
    movieList: List<Movie>,
    onBack: () -> Unit,
    onSearch: () -> Unit,
    state: LazyGridState
) {
    Column {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            state = state,
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(8.dp),
            content = {
                item(span = { GridItemSpan(2) }) {
                    CustomText(
                        text = "Popular Movies",
                        fontFamilyID = R.font.poppins_semi_bold,
                        fontSize = 24.sp,
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = 16.dp, start = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
                    )
                }
                items(movieList.size) {
                    TrendContentItem(
                        movie = movieList[it]
                    )
                }
                item {
                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
                        onSearch()
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}


@Composable
fun PopularMoviesLoadingContent(onBack: () -> Unit, list: List<Movie>, state: LazyGridState) {
    Column {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            state = state,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(8.dp),
            content = {
                item(span = { GridItemSpan(2) }) {
                    CustomText(
                        text = "Popular Movies",
                        fontFamilyID = R.font.poppins_semi_bold,
                        fontSize = 24.sp,
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = 16.dp, start = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
                    )
                }
                items(list.size) {
                    TrendContentItem(
                        movie = list[it]
                    )
                }
                items(6) {
                    LoadingContentItems()
                }
            })
    }
}

